# Ruby: when do we need protected methods?

Tags: ruby

There are a lot of supplemental information in the Internet about `private` and `protected` methods in Ruby, and about the difference between them. But I found no info regarding practical usage of the `protected` ones. When and why could we need to use them in real world? Could one provide an example, please?

Comment: I would rather ask when you would want a `private` method.

Comment: @sawa private methods are commonly used

Comment: A private method is internal to the implementation of a class, and it can only be called by other instance methods of the class or its subclasses.

Comment: Nope. That is protected method.

Comment: See *The Ruby Programming Language*  O`Reilly p. 232

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105572/discussion-between-dreamwalker-and-sawa).